# I am getting a "Object reference not set (...)." when I call context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().ToList() using SOLR in Sitecore 7

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7

I need some guidance here.

I am implementing a simple search using Solr and Sitecore 7.

I got the data indexed in SOLR and my code is pretty much it:

```
var resultSet = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Where(r => r.Content.Contains(keyword));
totalCount = resultSet.Count(); // results: totalCount=20
var list = resultSet.ToList(); //Exception
```

The Count() method works well, but when I try to get a list I get this exception:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.<GetSearchResults>d__a.MoveNext() +958
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +536
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

My mistake.

I am creating a custom configuration node and I forgot to put the fieldMap section.

```
<fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
```

At first I thought it would be merged with the defauldConfiguration but it didn't work that way.

Anyway, problem solved.